# MySQL: Efficiency of views containing GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, view

The fact that I haven't been able to come up (or research) a solution to this question means that I'm either too stupid to read the docs or it is in fact a complicated problem.

In a rather big database I often need a query like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE condition GROUP BY something;
```

This takes a fraction of a second to complete. So I put this in a VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW view_x AS SELECT ... GROUP BY something;
```

And when I then do

```
SELECT * FROM view_x WHERE condition;
```

it takes more than a minute to complete. Now it's easy to see why: In the plain SELECT, the DB engine first selects a few hundred results from millions of records and then does the aggregating and grouping only on the matching records. When using the view, it seems to first evaluate the entire dataset, aggregating and grouping everything, and then returns only the records meeting the condition and throwing away the expensively calculated rest.

Is there a more intelligent VIEW solution, or do I have to use the full SELECT each time?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the original SQL code for the view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_status1 AS SELECT                 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(J.ts_start) AS job_start,     
    J.id AS job_id, J.carrier, J.n_wafers,      
    count(W.id) AS n                            
    FROM job AS J                               
    JOIN wafer AS W ON J.id=W.job_id            
    GROUP BY J.carrier, J.n_wafers, W.status_id;
```

table job: 100k records, table wafer: 2M records.

Comparison is between these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM v_status1 WHERE carrier LIKE 'W96L00%'; -- very slow
```

versus the identical SELECT in the VIEW definition with the WHERE clause before the GROUP BY clause.

Some additional information: The query yields 9 records. Using the view it takes 19 seconds to execute. Using the direct query, it takes 0.000 seconds according to MySQL Workbench.

When I replace the WHERE clause in the direct query by a HAVING clause with the same condition at the end of the query, I end up at the same execution time as the query using the view.

Yes, I forgot some columns in the GROUP BY part. Put them in, doesn't make much of a difference.

Minimal example (5 seconds execution time):

```
CREATE VIEW v_status2 AS SELECT 
    job_id,                     
    status_id,                  
    count(id) AS n
    FROM wafer                  
    GROUP BY job_id, status_id;
```

yields 2 records given some job_id

Comment: You should share what's inside the "...", "condition" and "something"

Comment: There are no materialized views in MySQL (well...a temp table sort of behaves this way), so the performance of a view is totally dependent on the underlying query, and should not be better or worse, in general.  Please show us the SQL code you are running.  I doubt the view is identical to your first query.

Comment: It's always worse though :-(

Comment: @slaasko @Tim Biegeleisen Added the original SQL. The JOINs are not really necessary to understand the problem, they just exacerbate it. If I omit the table `job` and related columns and only select on `wafer` by job_id, the view takes 5 seconds vs. nothing using the direct select. See minmal example.

Comment: I can't explain your observations, though running `EXPLAIN` on the query might turn something up.  In the meantime, consider adding an index on `carrier` to speed up the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

well, I did the obvious and asked MySQL to EXPLAIN. The output is below. My interpretation is what I suspected all along: MySQL first builds a temporary table, doing all the hard work aggregating and grouping, and then selects only the rows matching the selection criteria. In other words, MySQL is not intelligent enough to first analyze the view to find where it can efficiently cull the original dataset and only work on the remaining records.

BTW, this has nothing to do with joins and indexes. You can see the effect with any sufficiently large two-column table.

```
id      select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1       PRIMARY <derived2>      ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    952929          Using where
2       DERIVED WS      index   PRIMARY ix_waferstatus_text     123     NULL    9       Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2       DERIVED W       ref     ix_wafer_job_id,wafer_ibfk_2    wafer_ibfk_2    5       jobwatch.WS.id  105881  Using where
2       DERIVED J       eq_ref  PRIMARY,job_ibkf_2      PRIMARY 4       jobwatch.W.job_id       1       Using where
2       DERIVED T       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       jobwatch.J.tool_id      1
```